# C# Compare Combobox Member Value with string

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to compare the string with Combobox Member Values. If string value matched, I need the index of matched value as well.

Comment: Winforms? WPF? UWP? ASP? What did you try?

Comment: Winforms
Actually I am developing a desktop application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly this will help you.

```
private void SampleMethod()
{
    cboExample.Items.AddRange(new string[]
    {
        "Element 1", "Element 2", "Element 3", "Element 4"
    });

    string searchedText = "Element 3";
    int index = cboExample.FindString(searchedText);
    MessageBox.Show($"Index of \"{searchedText}\" is {index}");
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Actually my issue is, I want to compare string with Combobox value. In your code, we are searching against Combobox Text.

Comment: @AsifRehmani are your values not of type string? Can you show us how you fill that ComboBox and what type are the items?